# Filter query by CURDATE()

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
SELECT *
FROM `summary`
WHERE submit_date = curdate()
AND submit_date > '06:00'
AND submit_date < '21:00'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

This is pulling all dates including today?  submit_date is a column that shows has DATETIME and it's not filtering them out like they should be.  What am I missing?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 2 limiting conditions should be comparing against the value returned by `TIME()` if it is a `DATETIME` column, and the first condition should be limited to the `DATE()` portion only.

```
SELECT *
FROM `summary`
WHERE
  /* Truncate to the date only to compare against CURDATE() */
  DATE(submit_date) = curdate()
  /* And truncate to the TIME() to compare against these time literals. */
  /* note also that the time literals may need seconds as well */
  AND TIME(submit_date) > '06:00:00'
  AND TIME(submit_date) < '21:00:00'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just compare the date portion of submit_date with date portion of current date and then the hour parts, as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM `summary`
WHERE 
    DATE(submit_date) = curdate()
AND HOUR(submit_date( BETWEEN 6 AND 21
LIMIT 0 , 30
```